# Make Webi report through the BICS Connection

Tags: business-objects, webi

I'm creating a little complex WebI report. I have the following mock up data

```
Type    Type_C  Amt
----    ----    --
1        #      $500.00
3        #      $1000.00
ABC      A      $10.00
ABC      B      $14.00
ABC      C      $15.00
AB       A      $10.00
AB       B      $14.00
DAB      D      $20.00
DAB      A      $10.00
DAB      B      $14.00
BC       B      $14.00
BC       C      $15.00
```

My requirement is to show report like this:

```
Type_Desc   Amount
-------     ------
A           $10.00
D           $20.00
E           $30.00
ABC         $39.00
AB          $24.00
BC          $29.00
DAB         $44.00
```

Comment: omg, my question and sample that I provided looks awfully horrible. I don't know how one could understand this :(. I'm willing to provide excel as an attachment sample if anyone looking for clean looking data. I did not find the attachment during the posting otherwise I'd have attached the excel sample.

Comment: @Isaac, thank you for fixing my tables, kudos to you! Is there some instructions that I can follow in the future so I don't have to struggle creating clean table?

Comment: There may be more comprehensive information out there, but these links about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [formatting code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/530233) (and data) are a good place to start. Honestly, a lot just comes from experience.

Comment: Back to your question, what is the relationship between your two tables? I do not understand the role of DimA in the second table.

Comment: That's how the data is coming from SAP business warehouse. you can say like a flat parent-child data (non-hierarchy). When you roll up DimA you will get to DimB. Another example would be State and City or Country and State.

Comment: So why are B, C, 1, and 3 not in the final results?

Comment: They do not need to be part of the calculation(analytic).

Comment: Is KF a dimension or measure? If you edit your question and provide a full screenshot of what you have in WebI that would be helpful.

Comment: The KF is measure. I just updated with better info and my report requirement. I could possibly send you the excel file with the data so you could quickly use it in WebI, just in case if you want.

Comment: This is an example of an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Read up on that and try to describe what it is you are trying to accomplish beyond "make these numbers look like that."

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your requirement, but try this.

I created two very simple queries based on the eFashion universe; Query 1 has City and Quantity Sold while Query 2 has State and Quantity Sold. I am not doing a union or any sort of merging here.

In my screenshot tables on the left are the results from each query. The table on the right is actually two tables. I just removed the table header (uncheck Format Table > General > Show table headers) from the second table and put it directly beneath the first table using relative position (Format Table > Layout > Relative Position). I set the column widths in each table to be the same so they will always line up. I also changed the dimension label to "New Dim".

[image]

Does that help?

Comment: Isaac, thanks. yes putting it in a table blocks isn't an issue. In your example, can you make a small tweak on "New_Dim" to show data like this:                                                                             New_Dim     Austin Boston Chicago DC Texas  and their corresponding KF (by city or state). Sorry I'm still knew to this blog and don't know how to format my thoughts so viewers easily understands it.

Comment: And also, regarding my table examples, let's forget about the first one and just focus on this                                                                                                                             
    DimB    DimA    KF                                                                                                   
and  expected report requirement only                                                              
    New_Dim     KF
-------     --
----    ----    --